# Assigning an array value in zsh for gsettings keybindings automation

Tags: zsh, array, gsettings

I think this script should work to set keybinds, but it's currently quite borked--UPDATE: it has been unborked, and now works. It is ugly though, and I'm soliciting ways to make it more elegant, as I need to copy-paste four lines every time I want a new key bind.

I claim that since zsh doesn't support 2d arrays, I'm probably best off rewriting this in python.... updated, that python script lives [here](https://github.com/thor314/.files/blob/main/setup/sh/configure_keybinds.py)

A question of how to set keybindings correctly lives [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/527990/add-a-custom-keybinding-with-gsettings-in-ubuntu).

```bash
#!/bin/zsh
# How many keybinds?
N=16
# Put keybindings here
k0=("keyboard dvorak nocaps" "Menu" "setxbmap dvorak -option nocaps")
k1=("launch code" "<Super>c" "code")
k2=("dropdown firefox" "<Shift><Super>f" "tdrop -ma -h \"100%\" -w \"50%\" firefox")

mkeys="org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys"
_locstr="/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom"
_ck="$mkeys.custom-keybinding:$_locstr"
M="$(expr $N - 1)"

# Create spaces for $N keybindings, emulating the command:
# gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/ media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/', '/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/ ']"
locations=""
for i in $(seq 0 $M); do
  locations+="'$_locstr$i/', "
done
locations+="'$_locstr$N/' "
gsettings set $mkeys custom-keybindings "[$locations]"


# issue commands. Have to paste 4 lines each time, kinda gross.
ck="${_ck}0/"
gsettings set $ck name    $k0[1]
gsettings set $ck binding $k0[2]
gsettings set $ck command $k0[3]
ck="${_ck}1/"
gsettings set $ck name    $k1[1]
gsettings set $ck binding $k1[2]
gsettings set $ck command $k1[3]
ck="${_ck}2/"
gsettings set $ck name    $k2[1]
gsettings set $ck binding $k2[2]
gsettings set $ck command $k2[3]

# test with:
# i=0
# ck="${_ck}$i/"
# gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings
# gsettings list-recursively $ck
```

Comment: Welcome, `for i in {0..$M}` won't work, the construct `{n..n}` doesn't allow parameters. You can use `seq`: `for i in $(seq 1 $M)`.

Comment: that actually seems to be working fine, I did check it.

Comment: The for loop will loop once, no matter the value of `$M`. Maybe that's what you interpret as working fine.

Comment: Try `M=5; for i in {1..$M}; do echo foo; done`.

Comment: [*"Brace expansion is performed before any other expansions"*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html), which means that `$M` is not expanded there.

Comment: That seems correct then. There's at least one other bug in the program; the way I'm evaluating $k: `  gsettings set $ck name "$k[0]"` seems pretty wrong. Is there an elegant way to get the first element of ki here?

Comment: Could you explain what you want to achieve with the loop that contain those variables? [edit] the question, don't add it in the comments.

Comment: @steeldriver updated. sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @schrodingerscatcuriosity, that's a limitation of `bash` and `bash` only, zsh (where `{0..10}` comes from actually) doesn't have that limitation.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas [OP's original question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/704309/1) was about bash, it was edited later and changed to zsh.

Comment: I would stay away from `os.system()` that invokes a shell to parse shell code, so you're introducing all sorts of problems including potential code injection vulnerabilities. It would be like using `eval` in shells. See `subprocess.run()` / `subprocess.call()` instead in `python`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some avenues for improvement:

```
#! /bin/zsh -

bindings=(
  'keyboard dvorak nocaps' Menu              'setxbmap dvorak -option nocaps'
  'launch code'            '<Super>c'        code
  'dropdown firefox'       '<Shift><Super>f' 'tdrop -ma -h 100% -w 50% firefox'
)

mkeys=org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys
locstr=/${mkeys//./\/}/custom-keybindings/custom
ck=$mkeys.custom-keybinding:$locstr

locations=() i=0
for name binding command ($bindings) {
  for type (name binding command) gsettings set $ck$i $type ${(P)type}
  locations+=( "'$locstr$i'" )
  (( i++ ))
}

gsettings set $mkeys custom-keybindings "[${(j[, ])locations}]"
```